# How to register RestController interceptor that works before message convertor?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, interceptor, spring-restcontroller

Is there are any way in `spring mvc` to register interceptor that intrercepts `RestController` return value before it serialized?

Something like `@RestControllerAdvice` but for return values.

I know that I can make around-invoke advice but I think there are should be some standart way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postHandle` method of `HandlerInterceptor` gets the HttpServletResponse object and by that time `HttpMessageConverter` has serialized the response. So in my knowledge, you won't get that. But the Rest Controller Advice can implement `ResponseBodyAdvice` to process the response before the `HttpMessageConverter`. Spring 4.3.x documentation for [interceptors](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor). Sample working code.

**Model**

```
public class Sample {
    private String property;
    // getter and setter omitted    
}
```

**Rest Controller**

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @GetMapping
    public Sample get() {
        Sample s = new Sample();
        s.setProperty("Some Property");
        return s;
    }

}
```

**Rest Controller Advice**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class SampleAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Sample>{

    @Override
    public Sample beforeBodyWrite(Sample sample, MethodParameter arg1, MediaType arg2,
            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> arg3, ServerHttpRequest arg4, ServerHttpResponse arg5) {
        // Get a handle to your response object and make changes here
        sample.setProperty("Overridden Property");
        return sample;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter arg0, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> arg1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```